# Other than Brownian motion, when else is it possible to define "normalized weighted infinite dimensional Lebesgue measure"?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01950) article Sourav Chatterjee poses the question, how do we define the measure:

$$d\mu(A)=\frac{1}{Z}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4g^2}S_{YM}(A)\right)dA$$

The $Z$ here is an infinite normalizing constant and $dA$ is "infinite dimensional Lebesgue measure". He said this is analogous to defining measure on Wiener space. This can be done rigorously by, for example, Kolmogorov extension theorem. He also mentioned various QFTs.

I'm curious, are there other situations where we can define (probability) measures on infinite dimensional spaces as some type of limit of finite dimensional weighted Lebesgue measures?

Comment: To be precise, this is not a " limit of finite dimensional Lebesgue measures" but a limit of such measures multiplied by some Radon-Nikodym (or here Boltzmann) weights which break translation invariance. That's why it can be done.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam sure, that is a relevant point. It's not just the measure but weighted Lebesgue measures.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: What do you mean by "other situations"? Other situations than which ones?

Comment: @AlexM. Than Brownian motion or the attempt here for Yang Mills

Comment: General Gaussian measures on infinite-dimensional spaces can be viewed like this, as something like $\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_{CM}^2)\,\mathcal{D}x$ where $\|\cdot\|_{CM}$ is the Cameron-Martin norm induced by the covariance operator.  Is this what you're looking for, or something more general?

Comment: As to the last paragraph, I think that measures on infinite-dimensional spaces are almost always constructed as limits of finite-dimensional objects, and you tend to prove things about them by getting dimension-independent results in finite dimensions and passing to the limit.  Other approaches are sort of the exception, in my experience.

Comment: @NateEldredge That last comment was really helpful (that approaches like this are the norm), thanks. The main infinite dimensional measure space I work with at all is Wiener space. It makes sense that that's the norm.

Comment: Does a product measure on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ fit the bill?  (e.g. a sequence of independent Gaussian RV)  $\mathbb{R}^{Z}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space.  Otherwise, I'm confused by the question.